# ListView inside StackPanel inside Grid doesn't scale

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, windows-8.1

In a Windows 8.1 application (.NET 4.5) I have (across two templates, because of Binding) a Grid which contains a StackPanel which contains a ListView.
The thing is, the ListView doens't scale with available space, instead shows a scroll bar.

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> <!-- IF I set MinHeight here, it grows -->
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"/>
    <ListView
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ementas}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp1}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            IsItemClickEnabled="False"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Template for the ListView

```
<StackPanel Width="310" Margin="5,10,5,10" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding data}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}"/>
    <ListView SelectionMode="None"
            IsItemClickEnabled="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding pratos}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource temp2}"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False">
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

And the template for the second ListView

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding descricao}"
    Margin="5"
    Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"/>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I'd like for the ListView with the scrollbar to have it's size scale to fit content, and only scroll if it runs out of screen space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an extremely common problem... the `StackPanel` does *not* resize its contents to fit the parent control like a `Grid` does. The solution is simple... don't use a `StackPanel` except for the simplest of lining up a few controls duties. Instead of this, use a `Grid` which will automatically fit all space provided by parent controls.